# Simple way to log parameter values in throws exception from methods in Java

Tags: java, exception

At the moment my exceptions are logging text and stack-trace:

```
throw new RequestValidationException("test exception", parameters, e);
```

I want to Collect all parameters for the throws exception in all methods.

```
HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();   
        parameters.put("testparam", message.toString());

throw new RequestValidationException("test exception", parameters, e);
```

Now i'm using a hashmap. I have to look at every method and check if it's using a parameter.  This will cost me days. There are like thousands of exceptions in the code, is there a simple way to show the values?

Comment: Do you mean something automatic, or are you asking for a way to create a message that contains parameter values?

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. Could you provide some pseudo-code that illustrates the behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

You can use slf4j-ext for logging method parameters. They are logged at the trace level.

```
private static final XLogger xlogger = XLoggerFactory.getXLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Then you can use at start and end of your methods like this:

```
protected void Method1(Message aMessage){
    xLogger.entry(aMessage);
    ...
    xLogger.exit();
}
```